# UIImagePickerController tutorial?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, class, uiimagepickercontroller

I am currently developing an application and I need to be able when pressing a button to open the camera and take a snapshot that I will attach to a .json file and send to my server.
I am searching on google and StackOverflow for the last couple of hours but all the tutorials seem very old (08'-09') or not match my needs. I know that all the work is done with `UIImagePickerController` class but I would like to have a working example. Does anyone know a good tutorial to get started for something like this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well if you google something like:

> UIImagePickerController and take snapshot put in json and send to server

Will be a bit hard. So, use [this](http://blog.hanpo.tw/2012/01/uiimagepickercontroller-and-simple.html) tutorial for the `UIImagePickerController`. By the way, the term for the search was:

> UIImagePickerController Tutorial 2012

Answer (score 28):

You should check this article from AppCoda [Build a Simple iPhone Camera App](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-camera-iphone-app/), very clear and simple :)

Take photo using the native iOS Camera app

```
- (IBAction)takePhoto:(UIButton *)sender {

    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil]; 
}
```

Read the captured photo (you have to implement `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    self.imageView.image = chosenImage;

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please note that you should post the essential parts of the answer here, on this site, or your post risks being deleted [See the FAQ where it mentions answers that are 'barely more than a link'.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) You may still include the link if you wish, but only as a 'reference'. The answer should stand on its own without needing the link.

Comment: Hello i need help, i have two cases 

1. A viewcontroller is pushed via navigation
2. A viewcontroller is presented

viewcontroller is same in both case and in that i have imageview
and picking image from photos(gallery). In 1st case i can see photo in image view after didfinshpicking

BUT not in 2nd case. 

Can any one help me???

Comment: @AbhishekThapliThapliyal Hi, that should be another question

Answer (score 0):

I came across this code [AQPhotoPicker](https://github.com/aqavi-paracha/AQPhotoPicker). This is quite easy to use with only one call, you will get photo from camera or photoPicker

Answer (score -1):

Try [this](http://www.zimbio.com/iPhone/articles/1109/Picking+Images+iPhone+SDK+UIImagePickerController). It's very simple, you just need to set delegate for a controller and call it. Google will help you, there are plenty of resources and working examples. For instance, [sample code from Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoLocations/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008909)

Comment: Sorry, it's a 2008 article. =/