# Allow user to change image to one from their gallery

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a `UIImageView` that has a `UIImage`.
What i would like is when the `UIImage` is clicked the user can select a photo from thier gallery to show in the `UIImageView` instead of the default image i have set

```
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    UIImage *myimg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ProfilePic.png"];
    imageView.image=myimg;
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(100,0, 80, 50); // pass your frame   here
    [setsView addSubview:imageView];
    imageView.layer.backgroundColor=[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius=20;
    imageView.layer.borderWidth=2.0;
    imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    imageView.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
```

EDIT: If I could make a view with a bunch of images and when an image is clicked it changes the "myimg" to the clicked image if that makes sense

EDIT #2:Also how would u save the photo the user chose and use it the next time the user opened the appliation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is to implement `UIImagePickerController` with `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary` as a source type.

There´re tons of tutorials and questions/answers here in stackoverflow.

Check for example this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11328909/uiimagepickercontroller-tutorial). It has pretty good answers with reference links to a sample code from Apple and other interesting tutorials.

EDIT #2:
Well, this also has many ways to be accomplished all depends on your use case. But a *quick and simple* way to do it is by using `NSUserDefaults`.

Eg:
This to save the image,

```
NSData * data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(yourUImage);
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:data forKey:@"userImage"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

and to get the image

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *data = [defaults objectForKey:@"userImage"];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

    yourImageView.image = image;
}
```

Comment: Take a look now. Hope it helps!

Comment: I tried the code but when i try to compile it gives me a bunch of errors

Comment: One error i figured out is you put standardDefaults but in IOS8 it is supposed to be standardUserDefaults

Comment: Is there somewhere easier i can contact u so i can send u a screenshot of the remaining errors?

Comment: Use of undeclared identifier 'forkey'

Comment: Ok. I see where. I did't write `data` before `setObject:` . Take a look at the first code block, I edited it.

Comment: Okay so now it compiles rght but when i run the app (i put the save code in the button that kills the view and the load code in the loadView) when i go to click the exit button the app crashes

Comment: Okay so the crash problem came from a image already being set but how do i display the saved image automatically in the UIImageView?

Comment: Load the image from the `NSUserDefaults` before you set it to the `UIImageView`

Comment: I thinkthe problem is the image the user chooses is not beng saved

Answer (score 0):

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageAction:)];
                    [self.imgPhotoStrand setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
                    [self.imgPhotoStrand addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

 -(void)imageAction:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender{ 
   UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Edit Photo"
                                                                                 delegate:self
                                                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                                   destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                                        otherButtonTitles:@"Camera", @"Select from Library", nil];
                    actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleAutomatic;
                    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
 }

 #pragma mark - UIActionSheetDelegate -

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
            {
                switch(buttonIndex)
                {
                    case 0:
                    {
                        if ([UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {

                            if (IS_IPAD) {
                                [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
                                     [self camera];
                                }];
                            }else if(IS_IPHONE){
                                 [self camera];
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:ALERTTITLE message:@"No Camara Found" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                            [alertView show];
                        }

                    }
                        break;
                    case 1:
                    {
                        if (IS_IPAD) {
                            [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
                                [self library];
                            }];
                        }else if(IS_IPHONE){
                            [self library];
                        }

                    }
                    default:
                        // Do Nothing.........
                        break;
                }
            }


        - (void)camera {
            if(![UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]){
                return;
            }
            UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
            //Permetto la modifica delle foto
            picker.allowsEditing = YES;
            //Imposto il delegato
            [picker setDelegate:self];

            [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
- (void)library {
            //Inizializzo la classe per la gestione della libreria immagine
            UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
            //Permetto la modifica delle foto
            picker.allowsEditing = YES;
            //Imposto il delegato
            [picker setDelegate:self];

            [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
        }


 #pragma mark UIImagePickerController Delegate
    - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{

        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{



                UIImage *image = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
                 self.imgPhotoStrand.image =image;

        }];


    }
 - (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker{
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UIImagePickerController` to get image from gallery and show it on image view

This code takes you to Gallery

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsEditing = YES;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

And then here is delegate method for `UIImagePickerController`

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    yourImageView.image = chosenImage;

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

This worked for me.
Hope it helps.

1]You can use custom button for each image so that when you click an image button target gets called and you can change the your image with the clicked image.

2]For storing the image you can use `NSUserDefaults` so that even though application gets closed your image is stored in `NSUserDefaults` So that you can use it the next time the user opened the application.

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(chosenImage, 1.0);
encodedString = [imageData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
NSLog(@"chosenImage : %@",chosenImage);
```

This will give you your image.

To set this image to `ImageView` you can use

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
yourImageView.image = image;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I cant use controllers. I am building with theos so everything i do is completly through code

Comment: Thanks this required a little tweaking and u forgot to mention delegates but i got it to work

Comment: That doesnt tell me how to get the image from NSUserDefaults